# Margin exists despite being set to 0 in stylesheet - CSS

Tags: html, css, margin

In Chrome when I open up Inspect Element on my webpage, I notice one of the divs has a margin on the right side that fills the rest of the page horizontally:

[image: Notice the right margin extending to the edge of the page]

As far as I know, no right margin should exist on that div. In the stylesheet of the html document, the right margin is set to zero. And, the box model in the Inspect Element window shows a right margin of `-`:

**CSS:**

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#header {
    /*this is the parent div of the div with the unexpected right margin*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #26519E;
    box-shadow: 0 5px 5px Lightgray;
}

#logo {
    /*this is the div with the unexpected margin*/
    width: 120px;
    height: inherit;
    margin-left: 180px;
    /*!!!*/
    margin-right: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

**Inspect Element:**

[image: The HTML layout]

[image: The Inspect Element box model]

**What could be causing this right margin on the `logo` div?**

If more information is required to determine what's happening, please tell me.

Comment: The right margin is 0? and there's no margin exist.

Comment: @Leonel Yes, it's set to zero. I just edited the css portion. I cannot understand the second part of your comment - what do you mean by 'no margin existing'?

Comment: margin-right: 0px; - does that do what you are expecting?  If this doesnt resolve it are you able to throw something up on codepen quickly

Comment: @Burrito I just tried that and it doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: @Jacob what are you expecting to right margin? as I can see you set the right margin to `0` and `-` is also means zero. *(what you have in the left is 180 margin, 0 border, 10 padding, and in the right 0 margin, 0 border, 10 padding)*

Comment: You have a fixed width set for that #logo. Remove it and your 'margin' should be gone

Comment: Divs are block elements. Block elements are meant to cover the full width of the line you place them in. The way block elements work in webkit is that it will automagically add a phantom margin in order to cover the full-width of the parent element the moment you limit its width; that is, as long as you don't float it, absolutely position it, or inline-block it.

Comment: @Pevara What if I want to have a fixed width for it? If I remove it, the div will span the rest of the page horizontally

Comment: @Leonel I expect no right margin. Yes, what you wrote is correct. Yes, written in the CSS is a right margin of zero, but it's not being displayed correctly/ like that. The reason I want to remove the right margin is so that I can place other divs beside the 'espanol' in the header at the same vertical position.

Comment: You can have a fixed width (`width:120px`) and use `display:inline-block`.  Just make sure you inline anything you add after `#logo`. http://jsfiddle.net/codyogden/LwL7ym8m/

Comment: @JeanLescure Ah, using display: inline-block; works marvelously. It has accomplished exactly what I wish. This comment should be an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A block-level element like a div in-flow (A div is a block-level element, not an inline element like a span, img or strong) has an automatic right margin because it (normal div's) want to be 100% of the width of the parent div.

Solutions are float:left (to get it out of flow), display:inline-block (to change its flow-abilities, as mentioned in the comments above, I'm not hogging credit :) ) and flexbox (which is relatively new so I wouldn't recommend jumping in on that just yet).

Also, have a look at [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) and its grid system to get better aligning for your website which also scales beautifully to phones and tablets.

Minor addition:

```
<div id="header">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

with:

```
#header,#main {
  width: 100%;
}
#header {
  background: brown;
  height: 3em;
}

.container {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 20em;
}
```

creates an easy (but not responsive) centered solution